# What is the best way to load/choose "controller" classes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm not sure if i'm using the correct terminology but I have several Controller classes that return objects using different data sources in my ASP.NET web app. ie

```
Product p = ProductController.GetByID(string id);
```

What I want to be able to do is use a controller factory that can select from different ProductControllers.  I understand the basic factory pattern but wondered if there was a way to load the selected cotroller class using just a string.

What I want to achieve is a way of returning new/different controllers without having to update a factory class.  Someone suggested i look at dependency injection and MEF.  I had a look at MEF but I've been having trouble figuring out how to implment this in a web app.

I'd love to get some pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this. You don't need a framework to do dependency injection (though hand coding them may bring you to a point where the IoC containers start to make sense).

Since you want to call the GetByID on multiple implementations I'd start with extracting an interface from the ProductController you have.

```
    public interface IProductController
    {
        Product GetByID(int id);
    }

    public class SomeProductController : IProductController
    {
        public Product GetByID(int id)
        {
            return << fetch code >> 
        }
    }
```

From there you can resolve the implementation in a number of ways, some examples:

```
public class ProductFetcher
{
    // option 1: constructor injection
    private readonly IProductController _productController;

    public ProductFetcher(IProductController productController)
    {
        _productController = productController;
    }
    public Product FetchProductByID(int id)
    {
        return _productController.GetByID(id);
    }

    // option 2: inject it at the method level
    public static Product FetchProductByID(IProductController productController, int id)
    {
        return productController.GetByID(id);
    }

    // option 3: black box the whole thing, this is more of a servicelocator pattern
    public static Product FetchProductsByID(string controllerName, int id)
    {
        var productController = getProductController(controllerName);
        return productController.GetByID(id);
    }

    private static IProductController getProductController(string controllerName)
    {
        // hard code them or use configuration data or reflection
        // can also make this method non static and abstract to create an abstract factory
        switch(controllerName.ToLower())
        {
            case "someproductcontroller":
                return new SomeProductController();
            case "anotherproductcontroller":
                // etc

            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
     }
}
```

It all sort of depends on who's going to be responsible for selecting which ProductController implementation needs to be used.

Comment: Dependency Injection (Inversion of Control) really can be useful in this situation. It allows you to change the behavior of your ProductController at runtime, as shown above.

Comment: Thanks, i've been looking at using some sort of DI framework.